# Putting a text entry as a pygtk menu item

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I am trying to extend a unity appindicator for project hamster. What I want to do is have a text entry directly in the indicator menu. I have seen this for example in the ubuntu memenu, but I cannot figure out how to get it to work with pygtk. I have searched for a while and found nothing. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: did you look at the code for that ubuntu menu?

Comment: The me menu is coded in C, and gtk in c doesn't map that well to pygtk so looking at it didn't help me out that much. I fear that it may have a custom C widget that was coded for that specific menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure there is no way to add that in a menu in PyGTK, but you might try a [borderless window popup](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkwindow.html#method-gtkwindow--set-decorated).